# jquery custom slider - auto animate slides

Tags: jquery

I have created a jquery slider. On clicking next or back buttons .animate function is used to show next list item. Both next and previous buttons are working but now i want slides to animate automatically after every x time. I could not figure out how jquery timeout function works.

```
current = 0;
current_slide=1;
$(document).ready(function(){
    width=951;
    var totalSlides=$(".slider ul li").length;
    $(".slider ul").removeAttr('width');
    $(".slider ul").attr('width',width*totalSlides);

    $('#next img').click(function(){
        current_slide++;
        current -= width;
        if(current_slide>totalSlides)
            {
                current=0;
                current_slide=1;
                //$(".slider ul").css('left',(totalSlides)*width);  
                $(".slider ul").animate({"left":current+"px"}, "fast");
            }
        else
            $(".slider ul").animate({"left":current+"px"}, "slow");
    });

    $('#prev img').click(function(){
        current_slide--;
        current += width;
        if (current_slide < 1) 
            {
                current = (totalSlides-1)*(-width);
                current_slide = totalSlides;
                $(".slider ul").animate({"left":current+"px"}, "fast");
            }
        else
            $(".slider ul").animate({"left":current+"px"}, "slow"); 
    });
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "jquery timeout"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below - just uses standard javascript setTimeout:

```
current = 0;
current_slide=1;

function runTimer() {
    $('#next img').trigger('click');
    var timeout = setTimeout("runTimer()",1000);
    }

$(document).ready(function(){
    width=951;
    var totalSlides=$(".slider ul li").length;
    $(".slider ul").removeAttr('width');
    $(".slider ul").attr('width',width*totalSlides);

    $('#next img').click(function(){
        current_slide++;
        current -= width;
        if(current_slide>totalSlides)
            {
                current=0;
                current_slide=1;
                //$(".slider ul").css('left',(totalSlides)*width);  
                $(".slider ul").animate({"left":current+"px"}, "fast");
            }
        else
            $(".slider ul").animate({"left":current+"px"}, "slow");
    });

    $('#prev img').click(function(){
        current_slide--;
        current += width;
        if (current_slide < 1) 
            {
                current = (totalSlides-1)*(-width);
                current_slide = totalSlides;
                $(".slider ul").animate({"left":current+"px"}, "fast");
            }
        else
            $(".slider ul").animate({"left":current+"px"}, "slow"); 
    });

    var timeout = setTimeout("runTimer()",1000);
});
```

Comment: Thanks..actually i never used timeout and i didn't know if there was a trigger function. Thanks for help.

Comment: kindly can you tell me if i can use different ways of animation with this code? and how can i make a function of my slider??

Comment: u are realy using setTimeout("runTimer()",1000); ? You know that like this it´s using "eval" what equals to evil :) ?

Comment: I suspect @Luke is saying you should either call it like this: setTimeout(runTimer,1000) or, alternatively, add an anonymous function directly into the setTimeout instead. The way I posted passes a string instead of a function. There is a slight performance difference I believe - probably better to follow 'best practise' advice so give it a go!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'different ways of animation' - please elaborate. If you are wanting to extend the options to have different transitions that could be quite a big topic and might be more suited to a new question thread

Answer (score 0):

> I could not figure out how jquery
>   timeout function works.

Just use setTimeout